# GPU temp in conky

Tags: conky

How do mesure gpu temp in conky.

Found this code:

```
${voffset 7}${goto 40}${voffset -4}Gpu: ${font Droid Sans:style=Bold:size=8}${execi 60 nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d+)./;'}°C${font}${alignr}Motherboard
```

But this onely gives the result 0 rpm.

so what to do

Comment: You can run `nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp` to see what it says, and then add the perl commands to see the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your version of Conky has not been installed with `--enable-nvidia` the easiest syntax would involve the following:

```
${execi 60 nvidia-settings -query [gpu:0]/GPUCoreTemp -t}°C
```

This would vary of course if you had more than one GPU installed. To see all of the available settings and GPUs run the following:

```
nvidia-settings -query all > all_nvidia_settings
```

and then open the file `all_nvidia_setings` with gedit...

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
${your offset}${your color}${nvidia temp}°C
```

For some reason the resulting display will look like this: `45A°C`. I can find no one sentence on how to eliminate the "A" but at least you will have a temperature to work with.

Comment: and if you get an error about $nvidia, install conky-all

Comment: When I use this technique, my conky displays a ${nvidia} and I get an error that says "nvidia: command not found" when I run that command in terminal.